# how to convert a nested JSON object to a URL query string to pass by AJAX?

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest, query-string

I am trying to write an Ajax request using JavaScript (without jQuery) and related to [this tutorial](https://plainjs.com/javascript/ajax/send-ajax-get-and-post-requests-47/), I have this function now:

```
function postAjax(url, data, success) {
        var params = typeof data == 'string' ? data : Object.keys(data).map(
                function(k){ return encodeURIComponent(k) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(data[k]) }
            ).join('&');

        var xhr = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        xhr.open('POST', url);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhr.readyState>3 && xhr.status==200) { success(xhr.responseText); }
        };
        xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        xhr.send(params);
        return xhr;
    }
```

and I can send data using JSON format like this:

```
postAjax(MY_SERVER_URL, { p1: 1, p2: 'Hello World' }, function(data){ console.log(data); });
```

and on the server, I only have `print_r($_POST)`, then the output is:

```
Array
(
    [p1] => 1
    [p2] => Hello World
)
```

But when I have a nested JSON, it will show me `[object Object]` as output instead of each array and object in my JSON. for example:

```
postAjax(url, { p1: 1, p2: {'test_name':'Hello World'} }, function(data){ console.log(data); });
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [p1] => 1
    [p2] => [object Object]
)
```

Can you please guide me how I should convert a nested JSON to a URL query string to pass by AJAX?

## Update

Please note that I can convert whole of my nested JSON to a string using `JSON.stringify` and pass it to the server, but as you probably know, if I use some libraries like jQuery, you can send nested JSON to the server and you don't need to decode the string on the server. the **point of this question** is exactly how some library like jQuery is passing data to the server that you can get it directly without any decoding?

Answer (score -1):

You can solved this by using two way

1. You need to send nested data as a string

   `postAjax(url, {
       p1: 1,
       p2: JSON.stringify({
           'test_name': 'Hello World'
       })
   }, function(data) {
       console.log(data);
   });`
2. Pass full data as a string

check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/39519299/6236938

Comment: yes I can, but when I am using jQuery, I can get sent data in server directly using $_POST or $_GET and I don't need to decode it.
I am trying to find out how jQuery is passing data