# Calling server data via JSON string

Tags: php, arrays, json, post

I need to POST a JSON ecoded string using the following parameters:

```
{"params":"query=ADDQUERY&hitsPerPage=6&filters=type%3Aartists"}
```

**I have;**

- An endpoint URL to query;
- An `input` search box and a search button to trigger the query. I need to replace `ADDQUERY` with the user input.

Can anyone shed some light on calling this info with JSON POST?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve, do you want to replace ADDQUERY only? how are you sending the data, we can't help without code.

Comment: @van : you just need to make this url dynamically from user input

Comment: @Hudson I'm trying to query the data on the server to return search results from a search bar, I haven't used JSON before so I have no idea how to format the code and link it to the input field

Comment: See this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39519246/make-xmlhttprequest-post-using-json

Comment: @Hudson how would I run that query string using JS based on the search box content?

Comment: WHat have you tried so far? It would help to see the existing structure and the problem you have with just posting that object - or do you want to transfer the whole JSON object as one string?

Comment: Please add all relevant code to the question. And you have tagged the question with PHP, so where is your PHP code? Whats all that JS code about in the fiddle?

Comment: @NicoHaase tagged with PHP as I thought it may be relevant or part of the solution, the JS is from the answer below, trying to get it working. If you have another method I would be very greatful for it

Answer (score 0):

Like this,

you can copy and paste this, just make sure to change the target url, and the input boxes querySelector , if it has an ID use '#' + the box id.

Edited your fiddle. Here's the full code.

```
    <div class="bodyparent">

<div class="searchbar">
   <div class="searchbar_inner">

      <div class="searchleft">
      <image onclick="search()" src ="search.png"/>
      </div>

      <div class="searchright">
      <input onchange="search()" id="searchinput" type="text" placeholder="Search...">
      </div>

   </div>
</div>

<div class="searchresults">

</div>
<script>
function search(){
  var box = document.querySelector("#searchinput");
  var json = { "params" :  "query=" + box.value + "&hitsPerPage=" + 6 + "&filters=type_artists"};

  var postData = JSON.stringify(json);
  //this is the string you requested above.

  var x = new XMLHttpRequest();

  x.open("POST" , "https://ufhsub9629-dsn.algolia.net/1/indexes/search/query?x-algolia-application-id=UFHSUB9629&x-algolia-api-key=69ed687a250f4c895cc73f6ee142a42e" , true);
  x.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(x.status == 200 && x.readyState == 4){
        //do whatever here
    }
  }
  x.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json; charset=UTF-8');
  x.send(JSON.stringify(json));
}
</script>
```

Its definitely working buddy:

[image: Proof]

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't rendering any search results for me, do you know why this might be happening?

Comment: I've run it successfully from Mozilla Firefox? Have you modified any other code?

Comment: Failed in Chrome? "message: "Object must contain only one string attribute: params near line:1 column:11"

Comment: Copy and paste my code above, i fixed that in the last edit buddy, I read your JSON wrong at first.

Comment: Brilliant thanks so much, this is now 'working' (kind of), the query string parses successfully, I'm not seeing any results returned from the query, do you know how would I display these in the .searchresults container?

Comment: you would have to use JSON.parse and iterate over the array... My best advice is go to w3 schools and look up javascript iteration.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you are trying to build your query using just PHP. You could look into using CURL to build the URL and send the request to a site or you could just encode the string with JS and redirect the page with the new URL.http://codular.com/curl-with-php  A better option would be to send the request with AJAX and prevent a page refresh. Hope this helps. http://jsfiddle.net/codedcontainer/xpvt214o/287107/

```
$('form#artistForm').on('submit', function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); 
    var inputVals = $(this).serializeArray();
    var singleInputVal = returnSingleInputVal('search', inputVals); 
    var queryObj = buildAjaxObject(singleInputVal);
    sendAjaxRequest('/echo/json', queryObj); 
});

function buildAjaxObject(searchQuery){
    var dataObject = {
        query :searchQuery,
        hitsPerPage: 6, 
        filters: ['artist', 'asc']
    }
 return dataObject; 
}
function sendAjaxRequest(url, dataObject){
    $.post(url, JSON.stringify(dataObject), function(data){
        $('#resultString').text(data); 
    });
}

function returnSingleInputVal(inputName, inputArray){
    for (var a = 0; a <= inputArray.length -1; a++){
    if ( inputArray[a].name == inputName){
        return inputArray[a].value; 
    }
  }
}
```